# Problems when trying to install tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to install tensorflow by using `"!pip install tensorflow"`(on python 3.8) but what I get is the following error message:

```
tf-nightly 2.5.0.dev20210102 requires grpcio~=1.34.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.32.0 which is incompatible.
tf-nightly 2.5.0.dev20210102 requires h5py~=3.1.0, but you'll have h5py 2.10.0 which is incompatible.
tf-nightly-gpu 2.5.0.dev20210102 requires grpcio~=1.34.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.32.0 which is incompatible.
tf-nightly-gpu 2.5.0.dev20210102 requires h5py~=3.1.0, but you'll have h5py 2.10.0 which is incompatible.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you already installed `tf-nightly` if not then do it using `pip install tf-nightly`a nd then `pip install grpcio`. The error itself clarifies that it needs the updated version of `grpcio` (`requires grpcio~=1.34.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.32.0 which is incompatible`).[Follow this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) to get complete details of the process to install `TensorFlow`.

Answer (score 0):

you should pip install grpcio==1.34.0 at first, i think it is better treat '~=' as '=='